# Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}

Tags: apache-2.4

When I run apache2 from command line (running the command, instead of the service), I've got this:

```
[Thu Mar 13 12:18:05.594522 2014] [core:warn] [pid 9268] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Mar 13 12:18:05.594732 2014] [core:warn] [pid 9268] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Thu Mar 13 12:18:05.594807 2014] [core:warn] [pid 9268] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Thu Mar 13 12:18:05.594867 2014] [core:warn] [pid 9268] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Thu Mar 13 12:18:05.594934 2014] [core:warn] [pid 9268] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Mar 13 12:18:05.617353 2014] [core:warn] [pid 9268] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Mar 13 12:18:05.617809 2014] [core:warn] [pid 9268] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Mar 13 12:18:05.617895 2014] [core:warn] [pid 9268] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

the line 74 is:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
```

I've updated Xubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 and it has Apache/2.4.6

Comment: Do you have the file `/etc/apache2/envvars`?  If so, what is in it?

Comment: @Ladadadada content of that file http://pastebin.com/sFt3vnVM

Comment: In my case I was getting the error because I didn't realize that `file:/var/log/apache/mutex` was a directory and not a file written by apache. As soon as I created an empty, writable directory of that name, all was well.

Comment: Are you running with enough permissions? It is possible that some enabled-sites conf file is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, because apache2 is expecting some variables to be set in its environment. So, the correct ways to run apache2 are with your regular service control scripts (service or systemctl), or apache2ctl (apachectl).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2` because default call to `bin` does not work right.

Details below:

On loaded test page, it says "The configuration system is fully documented in /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz." -> in that file it's written "Due to the use of environment variables, apache2
needs to be started/stopped with '/etc/init.d/apache2', apachectl, or
apache2ctl. Calling '/usr/bin/apache2' directly will not work with the
default configuration."

On my machine `apache2ctl restart` `apachectl restart` says `Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name ....`, but `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` works without questions.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to start apache by using the service command:

```
service apache2 start
```

See for the same problem and a more detailed answer at https://lists.debian.org/debian-apache/2013/08/msg00053.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.